# Struggling to use Plotly with data in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a dataframe that i want to convert to some interactive graphs on plotly. Here's a sample:

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="my_username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="my_key")

p <- plot_ly(usersDB, x = ~repos, type = "box")
p
```

But the graph I got is puzzling.

[image]

The x-axis is way off, something is obviously very wrong but I cant figure it out. My data looks fine and im taking the code straight from the Plotly tutorial. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `repos` is being treated as a character or factor vector. Cast it with `as.numeric(...)`. Do `summary(usersDB)` to confirm all the column types are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, do you know how this could have happened? When making my data frame i declared repos as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your data, column `repos` is of type "character" or "vector", that's why is being ordered alphabetically in your plot.

i.e.:

```
library(plotly)

usersDB <- data.frame(username = c("reeze", "miika", "tsavola", "Sannis", "tricky"),
                      following = c(302, 10, 21, 1273, 13),
                      followers = c(1035, 58, 33, 225, 19),
                      repos = c(150, 136, 53, "28", 6))


plot_ly(usersDB, x = ~repos, type = "box")

# wrong!
```

[image]

Here's a way to fix it:

```
usersDB$repos <- as.numeric(as.character(usersDB$repos))

plot_ly(usersDB, x = ~repos, type = "box")

# better now!
```

[image: another plotly plot]